# Firing checkboxlist selection change event using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have three checkboxlist,i am filtering datalist on selected index change .

There are too many postbacks.How can i fire changeevent without page refresh

```
    Foreach(Listitem li in chklist.items)
    {
     if(li.checked)
    {
     //Binding datalist by sending value to database.
    }
   }
```

Comment: Use jquery and ajax - http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please use jquery 
     $.ajax();
function. This is used to call url and send request and get response. You send the required attributes as request and try to format the response stream in json if your data size is big. It will give you good formation. Parse json in javascript and then display the result.
If any confusion ask. I will try.